# Change amount of text displayed on homepage posts

Tags: custom-post-types, text

I would like to be able to control what text appears in the boxes on [this homepage](http://www.ineldersfield.org/wordpress/) better.

Currently this just takes text from the beginning of the post.

How can I EITHER limit the length of this text OR Enter specific text into a field in the post to display here.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely your "Exceprt" area. See [the_excerpt](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt).

The excerpt is created from the first 55 or so words of your post automagically by WordPress.
You can also use the "More" tag ...
looks like `<!-- more -->` ... when editing your post to tell WP when to cutoff your exceprt text.

Also, depending on your theme, you can use/fill in the "Excerpt" box when editing a Post to specify the exact words you want WP to display when showing the Summary/Excerpt of the Post.

You can read on the Excerpt page linked above about how to customize the Excpert length to be any number besides 55 words if you are wanting to do that.

I hope this helps.